# How to fix nodemon@2.0.3 postinstall script error?

Tags: npm-install, nodemon

When trying to install nodemon, I get the current error if I try to install it either globally in a specific repo. It always returns the same error.

I've also tried to install any 2.0.x version without success, any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is present on GitHub with *open* status https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1663

It seems like it is a problem with Windows PowerShell (and it's version). The only workaround seems to be manually downloading a zipped nodemon package from [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and unpacking it directly into node_modules directory, then you remove `|| exit 0` from its package.json and run install script `npm install ../nodemon-master`.